# Keyboard hiding input lines on Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

There are many threads open due to this problem in Ionic, since Ionic v1. I've read and researched a lot and still haven't come with a definitive solution to this problem.

Well, my problem is like the problem of many other people using this framework. Here it goes:

I have a page with a lot of input lines like this (don't bother all the NaN or zeroes): [image]

Now, let's supposed I want to edit input number 7. I will click on it, and the keyboard pops up (I used Chrome Inspect to get the print, so the keyboard does not appear, but you can see that inputs 5, 6 and 7 are covered):

[image]

Then, I type something: [image]

**Boom!** The input line appears exactly where I wanted it to. Now, my question is: **How can I make the input line scroll to this position at the moment I focus it?** Is that even possible?

I tried `ion-col {position: initial !important;}` and `style="position: initial !important"` on `<ion-col>` from [this thread](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10629), but nothing seems to work.

If you think my codes are necessary, I can gladly post them here, I'm not doing this now because I don't want this post to be too big.

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little late, but I encountered the same issue in Ionic4. I managed to solve it by calling this method when an ion-input element gets clicked:

```
public focusInput (event): void {

    let total = 0;
    let container = null;

    const _rec = (obj) => {

        total += obj.offsetTop;
        const par = obj.offsetParent;
        if (par && par.localName !== 'ion-content') {
            _rec(par);
        } else {
            container = par;
        }
    }
    _rec(event.target);
    container.scrollToPoint(0, total - 50, 400);
}
```

You might want to adjust the if-statement to fit your code. The idea of this method is to recursivly calculate the offset to the upper most scrollable element, in this case the `ion-content`, and scroll this distance down using the `scrollToPoint()` method ([Docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/content/)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me to solve this problem on android ionic 5